# Can I change the gmail account associated with google play store?

Tags: google-play-store, gmail, google-account

When I got my android phone I had a gmail account, gmail-1, but have now created another account, gmail-2. Is it possible to transfer my play store info (i.e. app download history) from gmail-1 to gmail-2 and set gmail-2 as my primary email?

Answer (score 2):

Google has [this](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=63304) to say on transferring data between accounts.

It lists certain types of data that *CAN* be transferred and certain types of data that *CAN NOT* be transferred. Unfortunately Google Play Apps falls into the *NOT* category.

It's conveniently titled [Moving Product Data](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=58582).